# Bootstrap Dropdown doesn't want to towrk

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I literally pulled this code off of the bootstrap website and it still doesn't want to work. The dropdown menu for some reason is not working and I can't figure out why. I've tried just using the bundler js script but it still didn't work.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <title>To Do List</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown link
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

If anyone can figure out why I would appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting bootstrap 4 instead of bootstrap 5
Or, It might help, replace `data-toggle` with `data-bs-toggle` and `data-target` with `data-bs-target`.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "is not working"?

- Dropdown does not open ?
- or it does nothing after clicking on link?

You should be able to see dropdown appear/disappear when you click on `Dropdown link`.

If you expect something to happen, then your links in `.dropdown-menu` are missing `href` value so they can redirect.

You got included `css/styles.css`. Is there any chance that there is style which may break bootstrap dropdown styles? Also checking browser's `developer tools -> console` for possible errors would be useful

Comment: my mistake. The dropdown does nothing when clicked. The links do not appear.

Comment: ok, I see you solved your problem... I tried your code and opened it in browser and it worked as expected, so I thought there are styles overriding `.dropdown` css classes for example. Glad you solved it

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I used the code below and added `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"` to the dropdown.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-uWxY/CJNBR+1zjPWmfnSnVxwRheevXITnMqoEIeG1LJrdI0GlVs/9cVSyPYXdcSF" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kQtW33rZJAHjgefvhyyzcGF3C5TFyBQBA13V1RKPf4uH+bwyzQxZ6CmMZHmNBEfJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```